# attributes.headers getting lost after a http Request call in Mulesoft?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I am getting some attributes in an API but all getting lost after an HTTP request connector in mule4.
why is it happening?

Comment: Yes as @aled mentioned. That is how it is supposed to work  in Mule when it crosses the transport barrier (HTTP Request, JMS, Webservice etc). If you wanted to stored it for further usage, those field/value must be stored in Variable using `vars.whateverField`. Link is pretty old, but it applies the same/similar concept. Please read it through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668943/need-clarification-on-transport-barrier-in-understanding-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the connector's configuration properties -> advanced tab for the connector configuration (in this case the HTTP connector's "request" operation) and you'll find a *target variable* and *target value*. If you fill in the target with a name - this does an enrichment to avoid overwriting the Mule message. If you leave it blank (the default) it will save the message (attributes, payload) over the top of the existing one - which is what you're seeing now. This mirrors the old mule 3 functionality, but sometimes you want it to leave what you have there alone.

So for the *target value* you get to pick exactly what gets saved.. If you want just payload: put that in. If you want both payload and attributes - I'd use "message" as that will mean you get both payload and attributes saved in the variable. Of course you may not want as much saved, so feel free to put in whatever dataweave expression you like - so you could even create something with bits from anywhere like:

```
{
    statusCode: attributes.statusCode,
    headers: attributes.headers,
    payload: payload
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A connector operation may replace the attributes with those of the operation. If you need to preserve the previous attributes you need to save them to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behaviour of MuleSoft. Whenever request crosses to transport barrier it losses existing attributes. You need to preserve attribute before HTTP Request.